# Teamcity: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo when running "bundle install"

Tags: teamcity, bundler

## Background

I am trying to run cucumber scenarios on centos (via teamcity). The first step of the build configuration is:

```
bundle install
```

However, this just gives me the following errors:

```
[12:39:52][Step 1/4] Starting: /home/pgscutv/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script4075833203409573811
[12:39:52][Step 1/4] in directory: /home/pgscutv/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/37e3a4176e075735
[12:40:00][Step 1/4] Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
[12:40:06][Step 1/4] Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
[12:40:09][Step 1/4] Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
[12:40:11][Step 1/4] Rubygems 1.3.7 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
[12:40:12][Step 1/4] 
[12:40:12][Step 1/4] sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
[12:40:12][Step 1/4] Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rake-11.2.2.gem] in /home/pgscutv/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/37e3a4176e075735
[12:40:13][Step 1/4] sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
[12:40:13][Step 1/4] 
[12:40:13][Step 1/4] Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/addressable-2.4.0.gem] in /home/pgscutv/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/37e3a4176e075735
[12:40:13][Step 1/4] Using builder 3.2.2
[12:40:13][Step 1/4] sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

I am hesitant to do use `sudo` here as it is generally not recommended to do so with bundle. Also when I log into the machine using the same user as teacmity:

```
[pgscutv@pgsc-TC-build 37e3a4176e075735]$ gem -v
2.4.8
```

And when I add `gem -v` to the first buildstep, here is what I get:

```
[12:51:40][Step 1/4] in directory: /home/pgscutv/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/37e3a4176e075735
[12:51:40][Step 1/4] 1.3.7
```

## Question(s)

So my question is twofold:

1. Why is `rubygems 1.3.7` being used by bundle?
2. Is `rubygems 1.3.7` causing the issue with sudo as well?

Edit: feel free to suggest moving this to another site if appropriate.

Comment: You may add some `NOPASSWD:` entries in your sudoers file to ensure sudo proceeds even if not connected to the tty, as the code calls sudo itself and sudo says it can't ask for password.

Comment: If the rubygems program would actually connect sudo's standard input to the terminal, it would actually work correctly, ask for password once (first attempt)...

Comment: You may want to run `sudo true` before the installation to type the password before. This is just another workaround.

Comment: @PaulStelian : why would it call sudo?

Comment: I'm not sure why it actually would call sudo, but the thing is, it does. And you would use my last workaround (I recommend that one) to make sudo actually work better. It's possible it was put where it wasn't needed, it's possible something tries to install systemwide; either way, it is asking for root by itself (and currently failing)

Comment: Running sudo without knowing why isn't an option, put simply. But that wasn't actually my question. Re-read the last part :)

Comment: Try using another version of rubygems which ain't doing it

Comment: @PaulStelian: Read the question. I am trying to figure out why it is using the wrong rubygems version, and how I can change it

Comment: Then I suppose this is to be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: Try adding `whoami` as the first command of your script, as it still feels like wrong environment or user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all I needed to do was the following (before running anything on teamcity)

```
bundle install
bundle update capybara
bundle update selenium-webdriver
```